# What are the permissions I need?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

My folder at:

/usr/local/www/.ext_env_vars

has a bunch of files in it that my app needs to read. The user is 'webapp'

So, I changed the perms like so:

```
chmod -R 400 .ext_env_vars
chown -R webapp.webapp .ext_env_vars
```

The application can't read these. However, when I chmod 777, they are read by the app. So, it isn't that I have a path problem. Seems to be permissions only.

So, what would I have to do to the permissions to make webapp be able to read those files in the .ext_env_vars folder?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directory needs to be "executable" to access it. Try:

```
chmod 500 .ext_env_vars
```

Comment: Yep. And to read the files in it you don't even have to make it readable - just accessible.

Comment: Perfect. Works nicely. I did not know that it required the 'x'. Thanks! :)